# How to check if URL contain range of numbers and redirect the page with PHP

Tags: php, redirect

Google indexed some pages that i need to redirect to another page,
There is 2 kind of redirects that need to be done:

1. redirect url with specific parameters - **this have been done.**
2. redirect url that contain number from 861-1015  as part of the URL for example http://www.siteurl/category/1004-page - **this not done yet and i need help**.

What I need is if user search in google and he will get as a result one of the 2 condition the page will redirect to http://www.siteurl/new-page.

this is the code i have now:

```
// CODE FOR REDIRECT PSALAMS
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="https://www.google.co.il/" && 
($_GET['view']=="psalms" || $_GET['view']=="psalm" || 
$_GET['view']=="blessings" || $_GET['option']=="com_psalm") ){
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: https://www.rabenu.co.il/he/תהילים");
die();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: if the webserver is apache you ought to be able to use a `rewrite` rule in your `.htaccess`

Comment: Google `301 redirect`

Comment: Hi, it is Apache so can you please send the code or example with htaccess?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirectGoogleIndexPage() 
{
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $redirectUrl = "http://www.siteurl/new-page";

    if (!$path)
        return;

    $parse_path = explode('/', $parse_url['path']);
    $last_path = end($parse_path);

    // here you can do any condition
    // use like functions preg_match or strpos or others for get right path

     /**
     * for example check last path "1004-page"
     * preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last_path)
     */
    $number_of_path =  preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $last_path);

    if ($number_of_path >= 861 && $number_of_path <= 1015)
        header("Location: {$redirectUrl}");
}

redirectGoogleIndexPage();
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks its working but i did not understand why i need  the line "$url = 'http://www.siteurl/category/1004-page';" this is not a real URL and I gave it only for example but if I delete it your code not working anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: @Moni I guess that line was for demonstration. You'd need to get the current URL and place that instead of `'http://www.siteurl/category/1004-page'`.

Comment: Hi
The site url is https://www.rabenu.co.il but if i delete: http://www.siteurl/category/1004-page and write: https://www.rabenu.co.il the redirect not working anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: @Moni I understand you and edit code. I think now more clearly.

Comment: @Ravshanbek Ahmedov I edit the question so it is more clear now.